# ¿Por qué tengo valores repetidos cuando añado a una visualización de Tabla valores combinados de distintas tablas?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Digamos que tengo mi visualización de Tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A esta, las primeras columnas las agarro de una tabla "A", hasta ahí todo bien.

Creé una tabla filtrada (CALCULATEDTABLE) a partir de la tabla A pero con valores que cumplan ciertos criterios (que pertenezcan a ARGENTINA y que sean en MARZO), usé la tabla A como referencia como ya mencioné.

Regresemos a mi visualización de tabla, la cuarta columna ya no la agarro de la tabla A original, sino que la agarro de la tabla B calculada, pero resulta que tengo valores repetidos en cada fila de la visualización de tabla.

¿Por qué sucede esto?

Por ahí me dijeron que tengo que tener relaciones, pero tampoco veo que me resuelva nada esto, me podrían ayudar?